# Why am I getting JdbcSQLException (non-hex characters) with my H2 database / Spring boot application?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

So the short version, I'm guessing I've some sort of character encoding issue, or the DB is storing/returning the date in a format Hibernate/Spring-jpa doesn't like for some reason.

But I'm jiggered if I can work out what's going wrong!

Using Hibernate 5 to make use of J8 LocalDate stuff in entity props.

The database is being created and data inserted ok (you'll see in the log snippet below I get a date value back).

Log snippet:

```
2016-10-26 13:25:19.885 ERROR 1028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: 
Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[uk.co.deditech.entity.Person#2]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : 
EntityKey[uk.co.deditech.entity.Person#2]] with root cause org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "2016-03-23" [90004-192]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
at org.h2.util.StringUtils.convertHexToBytes(StringUtils.java:986) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:973) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
at org.h2.value.Value.getBytes(Value.java:422) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getBytes(JdbcResultSet.java:1077) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
<snip>
```

Gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker")
compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version:'1.4.192'
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public @Data class Person {
   ...
   @Column(name = "last_grading_date", nullable = true)
   private LocalDate lastGradingDate;
}
```

Spring boot auto DB creation script snippets:

```
schema.sql
create table PERSON
(
id int not null,
last_grading_date date
)

data.sql
insert into person (id, last_grading_date)
values (1, '2015-02-20');
```

Properties (issue was occurring before and after I added the encoding property below):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

EDIT:
After some more digging I discovered "validate" is a setting for the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property. So I tried that.

I'm now getting the following error during startup...

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [last_grading_date] in table [person]; found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [binary(255) (Types#VARBINARY)]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

Comment: Add `org.hibernate:hibernate-java8` as a dependency, without that it will not know how to convert from/to Java8 date time objects.

Answer (score 13):

I got it working by adding this dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I dont know why it does not work out of the box, but with this dependency it fix the issue.

I also added this property under properties: `<hibernate.version>5.0.5.Final</hibernate.version>`

My sample code for reproducing:

**Data.sql:**

```
insert into person (id, last_grading_date)
values (1, '2015-02-20');
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

**PersonRepository**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>{

}
```

**Person**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "last_grading_date", nullable = true)
    @Type(type = "java.time.LocalDate")
    private LocalDate lastGradingDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDate getLastGradingDate() {
        return lastGradingDate;
    }

    public void setLastGradingDate(LocalDate lastGradingDate) {
        this.lastGradingDate = lastGradingDate;
    }
}
```

**Applcation**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Person p = repo.findOne(1);
        System.out.println(p.getLastGradingDate());
    }
}
```

result: `2015-02-20`

---

**Added a working example on [GitHub](https://github.com/Pkurz/Hibernate5Java8Demo). The demo is build on `Spring-boot`, `Java 8`, `Hibernate 5`, `maven` and `java.time.LocalDate`.**

Comment: I was using CrudRepo rather than JpaRepo, changing to JpaRepo didn't help. 

I also changed the @type annotation to java.time.LocalDate again, still same error (Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "2016-03-23").

Comment: @DaFoot did you add the dependency in your application? I think you will need this library t get it working. If not I will add my pom.xml and you can give a try with maven.

Comment: Yup, tried adding dependency. Thinking there may be something else at pay here.

Comment: @DaFoot I added my working project on [github](https://github.com/Pkurz/Hibernate5Java8Demo). Clone it and try if it works for you. But its build on maven. Hope this is ok.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. 
Checked out and seems to work as expected. Frustrating!

Comment: No problem, its nearly the same what I provided in my answer. Just Check if it fits your needs.

Comment: See edited question. Added validation by hibernate of the schema created in schema.sql. Which you weren't using in your code.

I could change the column definition as that error suggests, but that doesn't feel right.

Tried changing to binary(255), now I get the string-hex error on startup instead.

Comment: @DaFoot Where is the problem to just use the code I provided? Its a working example and includes all the components you use. Or are there more difference in your application except the schema.sql? JPA should create the table without the schema.sql.

Answer (score 2):

*JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8 and the Date and Time API simply didn’t exist at that point in time. Therefore the @Temporal annotation can only be applied to attributes of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.*

If you want to store a `LocalDate` attribute in a `DATE` column or a `LocalDateTime` in a `TIMESTAMP` column, you need to define the mapping to `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` yourself.

Attribute converter are part of the JPA 2.1 specification and can therefore be used with any JPA 2.1 implementation, e.g. Hibernate or EclipseLink. I used Wildfly 8.2 with Hibernate 4.3 for the following examples.

**Converting LocalDate**

As you can see in the following code snippet, there isn’t much you need to do to create an attribute converter for LocalDate.

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

You need to implement the `AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date>` interface with its two methods `convertToDatabaseColumn` and `convertToEntityAttribute`. As you can see on the method names, one of them defines the conversion from the type of the entity attribute (`LocalDate`) to the database column type (`Date`) and the other one the inverse conversion. The conversion itself is very simple because `java.sql.Date` already provides the methods to do the conversion to and from a `LocalDate`.

Additionally the attribute converter needs to be annotated with the `@Converter` annotation. Due to the optional autoApply=true property, the converter will be applied to all attributes of type LocalDate. Have a look here, if you want to define the usage of the converter for each attribute individually.

The conversion of the attribute is transparent to the developer and the `LocalDate` attribute can be used as any other entity attribute. You can use it as a query parameter for example.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, 8, 11);
TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end", MyEntity.class);
query.setParameter("start", date.minusDays(2));
query.setParameter("end", date.plusDays(7));
MyEntity e = query.getSingleResult();
```

**Converting LocalDateTime**

The attribute converter for `LocalDateTime` is basically the same. You need to implement the `AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp>` interface and the converter needs to be annotated with the @Converter annotation. Similar to the `LocalDateConverter`, the conversion between a `LocalDateTime` and an `java.sql.Timestamp` is done with the conversion methods of `Timestamp`.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

**Example Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    ...

}
```

Comment: I am trying to use Hibernate 5 with Java8 which should be able to do the conversion without the converter steps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Spring Boot 1.5.10) all I needed to do was add the following to the pom.xml properties section

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
```

It looks like by default this version of Spring Boot uses Hibernate 5.0.12.Final

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the type of the column for `last_grading_date` in hibernate.
You can use:

```
@Column(name = "last_grading_date", nullable = true)
@Type(type="date")
private LocalDate lastGradingDate;
```

Change `LocalDate` class to `java.sql.Date` if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

This results in a different error, with and without the hibernate-java8  dependency mentioned:
Can not set java.time.LocalDate field ... to java.sql.Date

Comment: I meant, you should private `private Date lastGradingDate;` with `Date` being `java.sql.Date` rather than `LocalDate`

Comment: The question is about using the Java8 date classes. Which should be possible from HIbernate 5.

Comment: Oh yes, I should have read more carefully. Other answer seems to solve the problem, by adding a dependency with the right converter (and it seems that it doesn't need the @Type in this case)